# How can I mark or tag spots in a video clip during a live recording

Tags: editing, live

A couple of years ago I reacll seeing something on a crowd funding platform.  It was a way to 'tag' or 'mark' a portion of a video during live recording. i.e. if you just had a sports play that you wanted to find, you could just "click the button" to mark it.  Then, later on, you could have the computer s/w search for the marks.  it seemed like it would be useful for sports recording.  Has anyone seen something like this?

Thanks for your help.

Mark

Comment: Adobe had a good start on something called Adobe Prelude Live Logger, but I think they stopped development on it.  I'd love to be told otherwise.  Curious what else has popped up in this realm since last time I looked.  Key search terms you might want to use are: slate, timecode, metadata, and markup, in addition to the ones you're already using.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this largely depends on your budget and use case. If you are a TV network, especially a sports-centric network, many [media asset management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_asset_management) (MAM) systems add the logging capability on top of their existing search, organization, and workflow pieces. For example, Dalet has [Sports Logger](http://www.dalet.com/modules/sports-logger).

Answer (score 0):

Some cameras inherently support this.  It can be achieved via several ways but most generally consists of monitoring the timecode and generating a list of interesting time codes that are stored in metadata for the file.  The first time I saw this feature was actually a mark functionality that was built in to my Canon GL2 (pro-sumer SD mini-DV camcorder).  It isn't available on all platforms directly though (I'm not aware of a mark timecode feature on my Ursa Mini for example.) However, there may also be alternatives that can measure from either external timecode generation or by monitoring timecode on the output video feed (when timecode is included).

It might also be possible to use some other form of syncronization based on a simple stopwatch, however such timing would need manual sync for each file and would potentially drift over time if not genlocked since different timers can drift slightly over time.